# Android emulator creates multiple instances created with same project

Tags: android, emulation

I've just download Eclipse + Android SDK, I was making the classic hello world and then change some stuff around the code, but every time I run the same project Eclipse launch a new emulator. How can I keep running the same app on the same emulator? It's boring waiting the emulator finish loading (it takes ages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start emulator only once. After that you need not to close it after the first run. Your application will be installed automatically on the running emulator.

Comment: I have the emulator running, but If I re-run de app another emulator is launched instead of run the app on the previously launched emulator. Is there a configuration?

Comment: Right click on the project-> Run as -> Run configuration