# android - multiple emulator instances

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

whenever i run the android app in eclipse it runs in new emulator(so multiple emulator instances), i tried configuring in "Target" of "Run Configuration" this will solve the problem till next restart of the eclipse IDE though it saves the configuration. is there any permanent solution
-Thanks

Comment: does this help you ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591563/android-emulator-creates-multiple-instances-created-with-same-project

Comment: please post the android console logs during this problem behaviour

Comment: Sunil, I tried again, and it worked !! first opened the emulator using AVD manager and then run the app.  just running the app without emulator open cause problem.

Comment: yes i thought the same, since i faced this issue before. anyway happy that i helped you

Answer (score -1):

You can chose the target if you start multiple instances of emulator by the command line interface of the emulator tool of android tools. More info you can see on http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html#startup-options.
Regards.

Comment: That's the same as the Target option in the Run Configuration mentioned in the question, so it will not change anything.